# Ayuda con un query agrupar datos

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hola tengo una base de datos y quiero agrupar unos datos, la base de datos esta estructurada de la siguiente manera

```
Lote  |  Surtio  |  Lugar  |  Fecha
```

Todos son tipo string, y tengo el siguiete query

```
 SELECT surtio , lote FROM filtrado
    where linea = 'pilas' and fecha like '28/abr/18%'
```

con este obtengo los datos pero me salen sin estar agrupados, sale el nombre de la persona mas el numero del lote pero por ejemplo si el lote tiene 5 cosas esa persona sale 5 veces con el mismo no. de lote y pues lo que quiero es que se agrupen las personas con el numero de lote, intente con un group by pero no se puede por el simple echo de que una persona puede tener 2 o mas numeros de lote, y aqui es donde estoy atorado, si me pudieran ayudar a resolver esto lo que busco es tener el siguiente resultado

```
Surtido    |     Cantidad Lotes

Pedro                   5
Juan                    2
```

Que me digan la cantidad de lotes distintos que tienen asignados y tambien poder tener lo siguiente

```
 Surtido    |     Lote

Pedro             55504
Pedro             55201
Pedro             66666
Pedro             45646
Pedro             34213
```

Ayuda a como lograrlos que por mas que lo intento no se me ocurre como, de antemano gracias

Comment: `SELECT surtio, COUNT(lote) FROM filtrado where linea = 'pilas' and fecha like '28/abr/18%' GROUP BY surtio, lote`?

Comment: Si funciona y para la otra parte utilice el count(distinct) gracias